# How can i make jquery filter special characters too?

Tags: jquery

I have a code that filters rows which i get from database query.. It works fine but it does not show the rows which start with a special character like "Ç, Ş, Ö, Ü"..

Forexample if i write Dar to input area it will list Daria, Darian, Dariko, Dartonal but if i write Çar to input area it will show nothing.. How can i fix this in this code? Thank you..

```
var $rows = $('#table tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {

    var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
        reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
        text;

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
        return !reg.test(text);
    }).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`"text/html; charset=utf-8"` in your page header Or in your response.

Comment: My page has this <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: How about your JSON data? is that encoded too? I'm guessing you are getting your database results from an Ajax call?